# Can GEF use SWT Window as a popup window?

Tags: swt, eclipse-gef

I am doing a project using GEF. I need to open a popup window when double click the model in the canvas.

I create a SWT window and let GEF to open it. But the problem is it casue an exception:

Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access)

when running following code.

```
     while(!shell.isDisposed()){ 
        **if(!display.readAndDispatch()){** 
        display.sleep(); 
        }
        }
```

What i did in my project is create the SWT window, then make a thread to run it, and call the thread in my model's editpart like this:

```
public void performRequest(Request req)
{
            swtthread aa = new swtthread();
            aa.start();
    }
```

Do possible a GEF can use SWT window as a popup window or is there any other way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sound strange, but I have no experiences with GEF though. According to [this SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread) you call UI method from non-UI thread, try to wrap the code with

```
display.syncExec(
  new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
      ... // your code
  }
});
```

You can also use asyncExec, depending on your needs..